# WiFi often disconnects using RTL8192CU on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, internet, 17.10, realtek-wireless

I use **Ubuntu 17.10** and the following USB adapter:

```
lsusb  | grep -o 'ASUS.*'
```

> ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N10 Nano 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek **RTL8192CU**]

```
sudo lshw -class network | grep -o '.*rtl.*generic'
```

> configuration: broadcast=yes driver=**rtl8192cu** driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic

When the computer starts the Internet works fine (excepting the upload and download speeds which are 3 times slower than for another device), but after a while (usually just a few minutes) the **Internet goes down** and I need to run the following command in order to make it available again (or to wait about more than 5 minutes for auto-reconnect):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

I read [here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7):

> The wireless Realtek chipsets RTL8188CUS and **RTL8192CU** should **run well** on the **default RTL8192CU driver** (at least since the introduction of the 4.4 kernel series). So they should work fine out of the box. Plug and play, **no action needed anymore**.

The driver from CD seems deprecated for this kernel version.

**Disabling IPv6** from my WiFi setting/for the whole system **didn't fix** the problem.

Is there a problem with the driver?
Or is there something else that can make it fail after a while?

---

### Edit:

#### iwconfig

Running `iwconfig`shows a similar output (all of them show `Power Management:off`) with 2 differences:

- before the first disconnect

  ```
    Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
    Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0
  ```
- after disconnect

  ```
    Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
    Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:135   Missed beacon:0
  ```
- after a reconnect (restarting the network-manager service)

  ```
    Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
    Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0
  ```

#### journalctl

```
# sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
```

> ...
>   dec 25 22:59:50 ... NetworkManager[...]:   [...] manager: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
>   dec 25 22:59:50 ... NetworkManager[...]:   [...] manager: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled

The wireless disconnected at about 23:10:00 and after about 5 minutes:

> dec 25 23:15:10 ... NetworkManager[...]:   [...] connectivity: (wlx...) timed out
>   dec 25 23:15:26 ... NetworkManager[...]:   [...] policy: set '...' (wlx...) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
>   dec 25 23:20:10 ... NetworkManager[...]:   [...] connectivity: (wlx...) timed out

#### modprobe.d

Adding the following files/lines didn't fix the problem:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf
```

> options rtl8192cu fwlps=N

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

> blackist rtl8xxxu

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf  | grep rtl
```

> blacklist rtl8xxxu
>   blacklist rtl8192c_common

Comment: **Check** if **the** power **management** is **on** with **iwconfig**.

Comment: @mikewhatever , Power Management is always off. I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was **fixed** using the instructions from [here](https://appuals.com/ubuntu-16-04-to-17-10-wifi-and-ethernet-problem/):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/8192cu-disable-power-management.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
reboot
```

I hope that it's not just a coincidence, but it worked for the last 1 hour.

Until now, I ignored the posts that included this GitHub URL: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes because of the README.md file that specified the following:

> **!! This driver is DEPRECATED !!**

> The new rtl8xxxu driver initially introduced in kernel 4.4 works pretty well these days, and you almost certainly should prefer it to this repository.

> If rtl8xxxu gives you problems, try troubleshooting it before installing this driver. Known things to look for are:

> Some devices require that power management be disabled in NetworkManager. Follow the instructions further down to disable power management in NetworkManager.
> Make sure to blacklist the older rtl8192cu driver, which tends to be loaded by default otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would try blacklisting the other module that is loaded and reboot

```
echo "blackist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

Comment: Which is "the other module"? I only see  *RTL8192CU*.

Comment: Look at results for `lsmod | grep rtl` and you should see the rtl8xxxu module is loaded

Comment: I did this, but the problem is still there.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and paste the results to paste.ubuntu.com and post a link